# Warning: 0x80019002 at Foreach Loop Container

Tags: ssis

i have a main package and a child package. when i execute my main pacakge it comes to data flow tasks loads the tables but then data flow task goes red and i see following error messages :

---

```
Warning: 0x80019002 at Load Import Table: The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (1) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
Task failed: Load Import Table
Warning: 0x80019002 at Sequence Container: The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (1) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
Task failed: Execute Package Task
Warning: 0x80019002 at Foreach Loop Container: The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (1) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
Warning: 0x80019002 at FacetsXref_Main: The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (1) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
SSIS package "FacetsXref_Main.dtsx" finished: Failure.
The program '[2948] FacetsXref_Main.dtsx: DTS' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

---

As you can see it doesnt specifically show what the error is. In data flow task i am loading sql table from excel sheet and there are some other tasks, data conversion, derived column, statistics logging component (provides statistics logging for ETL processes) and an OLEDB destination.

Does anybody know what is wrong?

I am using SQL Server 2005.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the MaximumErrorCount in the properties window of for-each loop container. Set it to 1000